# Can not view the below webcam stream using ffserver + ffmpeg on osx

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, ffserver

I an lost trying to stream my webcam as mpeg stream using ffserver + ffmpeg.
I have both installed on OSX Yosemite (10.10.13) with the below ffserver.conf

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog /Users/admin/Documents/ffserver/webcam.log
NoDaemon

<Feed webcam.ffm>
    File /Users/admin/Documents/ffserver/webcam.mjpeg
    #FileMaxSize 200K
    #ACL allow 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
</Feed>


<Stream webcam.mjpg>

# coming from live feed 'webcam.ffm'

Feed webcam.ffm
Format mpegts

VideoCodec libx264
VideoFrameRate 24
VideoBitRate 512
VideoSize 640x480
#AVOptionVideo crf 23
#AVOptionVideo preset medium
# for more info on crf/preset options, type: x264 --help
#AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

NoAudio

</Stream>
```

running the below ffmpeg stream to the server

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "0" -vcodec libx264 -s 640X480 http://localhost:8090/webcam.mjpg
```

if I run ffmepg to output as a file I can access the webcam video but I can not see the stream using vlc (i get connection verification from ffserver)

any idea why ?

thanks 
nadigo

Comment: Do you get any output (stdout/stderr) from ffserver? I think you'll want to uncomment the AVOptionVideo options for crf and preset, because x264 will abort with your current settings and ffserver will thus never actually stream anything.

Answer (score -1):

U will add libx264 ,and build out in ffmpeg, or u try to build ffmpeg with network issue, and --enable-protocols --enable-network  and enable some demuxers.